# Does State Parlor give bonus for dwellings added after the fact?

Tags: caverna

When the state parlor is built, and a dwelling is later added, does the player get the two food bonus?

One school of thought is that the bonus is applied only once for the parlor itself.  Another school of thought is that the bonus is applied to each dwelling once.

This has implications for the milking and weaving parlor as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the revised English language appendix (page A5), it states (all bold and italics in the original)

> **When building** the State parlor, **immediately** *(and only once)* get 2 Food from the general supply for each Dwelling that is *(horizontally or vertically)* adjacent to the State parlor.

This unambiguously indicates that later dwellings do not provide a further 2 Food bonus. The same language is used for the milking and weaving parlors.